# Aggregating data from two collections

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question concerning LINQ and aggregating data. I have two csv files that I filled with dummy data that I am using to practice with.

The first csv file (Factors) contains the following fields:

- ZipCode
- FactorType
- FactorValue

Sample Data

- 31513,Type1,0.619046413
- 31515,Type1,0.62013599
- 31563,Type1,0.912988865
- 31513,Type2,0.619046413
- 31515,Type2,0.62013599
- 31563,Type2,0.912988865
- 31513,Type3,0.619046413
- 31515,Type3,0.62013599
- 31563,Type3,0.912988865

---

The second csv file (Counties) contains the following fields:

1. ZipCode
2. County

Sample Data

- 31513,Appling
- 31515,Appling
- 31563,Appling
- 31624,Atkinson
- 31642,Atkinson
- 31650,Atkinson
- 31510,Bacon
- 39870,Baker
- 31034,Baldwin
- 31059,Baldwin
- 31061,Baldwin
- 31062,Baldwin

I am attempting to get an average of FactorType by County using LINQ.  I have a query that returns the FactorType for each ZipCode by County, The code and a screenshot of the output is below.

```
var query =
            from county in countyRecords
            join factor in factorRecords on county.Zipcode equals factor.Zipcode
                into factorGroup
            orderby county.County
            select new CountyFactor
            {
                cf_county = county,
                cf_factors = factorGroup
            } into result
            group result by result.cf_county.County;
```

[image]

My Goal is to get an average of each of the factor types, For Example:

CountyName

- Average Type1
- Average Type2
- Average Type3

My thoughts are to take the results of the first query and use them in a second query to obtain those results but I do not know how to do that.  The code below is as far as I have got but do not know how to complete it.

```
var query2 =
            from data in query
            group data by data.Key into averageGroup
            select new
            {
                average = averageGroup.Average()
            }
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your goal correctly, you want to get average by country and type. You can achieve that grouping by 2 fields. To get average you need to specify the field. I assume this should help you:

```
var query2 =
            from data in query
            group data by new { data.Key, data.Country }
            into averageGroup
            select new
            {
                type = averageGroup.Key.Key,
                country = averageGroup.Key.Country,
                average = averageGroup.Average(el => el.Value)
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
countyRecords.Join( FactorRecords, c => c.ZipCode, f => f.ZipCode, (c, f) => new { County = c, Factor = f }).GroupBy(Factor.Type).Select( x=> new { x.key, x.Sum(Average) }).ToList( );
```

I don't understand if you need the sum of all average. Replace sum with max with obtains the max average, min to the minimum average and Average for average of them.